# Host do not have forwarding table?

Tags: networking, routes, ip

Suppose there are three routers between a source host and a destination host. Ignoring
fragmentation, an IP datagram sent from the source host to the destination host will travel
over how many interfaces? How many forwarding tables will be indexed to move the
datagram from the source to the destination?

answer: 8 interfaces; 3 forwarding tables

I cant understand, as I know the host also have a forwarding tables. because host also has a routing table

but why this answer is 3 forwarding tables. other people also saying 3 forwarding tables.

Could you explain this to me?

I understand in this case through 4 forwarding tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d personally say this question has no answer in gereral.
Just think about the following:

Router Eth0 has two networks configured, 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24
The packet has to travel from host with IP 192.168.1.5 to the host with ip 192.168.2.10
In this case your packet enters your router at Eth0 and leaves at Eth0 again so your number of interfaces in use is 7.

Regarding forwarding tables, many sources online confuse them with routing tables so things don´t get easier at all. 
I know in Win 2000 you could show information about your routing table and also the information about the forwarding table. 
For me this means that, at lease windows 2000, had an own forwarding table also meaning that it should be 4.

Anyways, since you could build some device that does not have routing nor forwarding tables this question cannot be answered.

Comment: hm... okay. thanks. This problem can only be solved by attaching clear conditions. I wonder, is it correct to say that hosts generally have routing tables?

Comment: Well routing tables typically work on layer 3 and forwarding on layer 2.
If your host communicates through layer 1 (basically streight to the cable) it would not be safe to say, also if it uses something different from MAC and IP protocols.
Anyways when you´re talking about the most common networks then it´s pretty much safe to say they all have a routing table, but noch 100 % save.